# Getting nginx error when I am trying to configure nginx on prometheus using https secure connection

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, prometheus

i am getting nginx error when I am trying to configure nginx on prometheus using https secure connection

below is my nginx.conf file

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        server_name  nginxserver.com;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location / {
          proxy_pass                            http://10.23.45.6:31866;
          auth_basic                            "Prometheus";
          auth_basic_user_file                  ".htpasswd";
          proxy_buffering                       off;
          proxy_set_header Host                 $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
        }
    }
}
```

Can any one help me here what is going wrong .

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: i was able to resolve it, thanks for asking